# Get a formula for a cell in excel substituting all references to a cell with another formula with it's contents

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Based on comments, I am clarifying what I am asking for.

**I want to get a nested formula across multiple cells flattened to a single formula.**

The following example is just to demonstrate how you could do it manually.
However, the formulas can be of any kind/type and not at all related to the example below.

I was curious if the following was possible using code/tools/excel itself -
[image: Excel with formulas showing]

As you can see in the image, the `in hours` formula is quite simple, but it is actually composed of a bunch of formulas from the other cells.
I was wondering if it is possible to get rid of the intermediate calculations by getting a single formula that is generated by using all the formulas in a single giant formula.

*While it's easy to design and debug large formulas this way, in production naive users can easily destroy parts of the formula by trying to modify the sheets. You could protect it with locking sheets and making other things unlocked but that also has unintended side effects of not being able to expand the formula range, or adding new rows ...etc.*

So for production I was wondering if it was possible to get a single formula answer for something that is composed this way.

In the example above, we are trying to calculate numeric hours from string hours.

```
in hours = in seconds / 3600 = O2 / 3600
in seconds = HOURS * 3600 + MINUTES * 60 + SECONDS
HOURS = extract digits if they exist between 'h' and beginning of string
MINUTES = extract digits if they exist between 'h' and 'm'
SECONDS = extract digits if they exist between 'm' and end of string
```

so if you were substitute the formulas manually it would come out looking like this

```
in hours = (HOURS * 3600 + MINUTES * 60 + SECONDS) / 3600 
= (extract digits if they exist between 'h' and beginning of string * 3600 + extract digits if they exist between 'h' and 'm' * 60 + extract digits if they exist between 'm' and end of string) / 3600
```

As you can see this example is quite simple, but I was wondering if it was possible to do it for other complex composite functions?

Excel already does all this calculations by itself in some sort of [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) I assume, as it already detects cyclic dependencies and such. So there must be a way to do it ourselves? or hook into excels underpinnings to extract the same formula?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably possible to do what you are after, but a UDF might be neater if you can use it.

```
Option Explicit

Function MyHrs(MyType As String, target As String) As Single

Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
Dim Hrs As Long, Mns As Long, Ss As Long
On Error Resume Next

x = InStr(target, "h")
y = InStr(target, "m")
z = InStr(target, "s")

Hrs = Left(target, x - 1)
Mns = Mid(target, x + 1, y - x - 1)
Ss = Mid(target, y + 1, z - y - 1)

If MyType = "h" Or MyType = 1 Then MyHrs = Hrs + Mns / 60 + Ss / 3600
If MyType = "m" Or MyType = 2 Then MyHrs = Hrs * 60 + Mns + Ss / 60
If MyType = "s" Or MyType = 3 Then MyHrs = Hrs * 3600 + Mns * 60 + Ss

End Function
```

Open up the developer window using ALT + F11, then insert a module and paste the code. In the sheet use it as follows:
[image]

This one could probably do with some more coding to avoid the errors generated, but it should work to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: Oh I know that. The example is contrived to demonstrate what I mean. I want a generic solution for any use case. Have an upvote for the code anyway

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a generic solution, the code can be adapted to be as generic as required and obviously simplifies the formula in the cell. To do what you are after will require a very long formula that would be awkward to modify for anything outside your contrived example.

Comment: I have re-read your question, and think I see where you are going. If the example you have pasted is not actually that relevant you should not make it so prominent, are you familiar with the "indirect" function? It might be worth rewriting the question title, putting the example at the end rather than the beginning, and specifying the actual point with a bit more clarity... I think you have used some technical language that is obviously clear to yourself and maybe others in the field, so maybe target those individuals in the title.